# Speed from Different EC2 Regions

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm based in the UK, as are all users of my web app, and currently host in the EU-West region.  The US-East region is quite a bit cheaper and I'm using a service from another company that locate their servers in the US-East region (meaning that I'll have data transfer costs between regions if I kept things in the EU). Has much of a speed difference am I likely to see between the two?

(I could do a test myself but I'm hoping someone else has already done it :) )

I'd appreciate insights that anyone has. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a nice service which compares the speed and latency of different clouds and different regions:
http://cloudharmony.com/speedtest

You can pick only the amazon services and test all regions.

Comment: You'd need to run that from AWS though - it specifically measures your connection from your browser to the specified resources

Comment: CloudHarmony was acquired by Gartner in 2015 and this link is now dead. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Speed within Availability zones is very impressive. When you start talking about across continents you're going to get some lag and much less bandwidth. I think it would depend what you're passing over the network whether it would work in your case or not. However, to answer your question there is a very large difference in speed.

Comment: I tested ping speed (from my home connection) to a server in the US-East region vs. the EU-West region and got 25ms vs 95ms. It seems like the higher latency would make a big difference to how fast the web app "feels" to the user

Comment: Its not just the latency you have to worry about. Actually transferring files is going to be much different. Inside the US-East your on a multi gigabit network. Once you start transferring files across the EU-West you're going to see that the connection is much slower.

Comment: Are you saying US-East -> EU-West is slower or EU-West->EU-West is slower? I presume you meant the former. My point on the latency was that there's enough of a difference that I need to figure out how to have the app in the EU-West region rather than US-East... so I think we're in agreement :)

Comment: Yes, latency is often a problem depending on the application. Transfer speed and latency should be the same no matter which direction your going. My point is the latency is only part of the problem. Latency is the time it takes to get a response. If you send a 100mb file between the two zoens you may have a latency of 95ms but the file will take 10 minutes to transfer. If you transfer the same file inside the same region it could take maybe 2 minutes.

Comment: We have servers in EU-West-1A and 1B. Ping time inside a zone is .25ms, between zones 1.1ms.