# Redis - scaling over different ec2 regions

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, cluster-computing, regions

as I understand it's technically possible to have redis cluster with nodes spreaded by different regions in amazon cloud (EC2) - so I will be able to obtain the same data in machines in each region.

But here is 2 questions I am not sure:

1. how it would impact on redis' speed? As guys measured ([Speed from Different EC2 Regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418662/speed-from-different-ec2-regions)) - there is about 4 times difference. What should it mean for redis?
2. how much would it cost for me? Or in other words - how much service traffic does reddis generate when work in cluster (for example, by one node in both of two regions)?

I have no any practical experience with redis, but seems it can be very useful for my purposes.

thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Redis Cluster is not ready yet and have not been delivered. What is available now is master/slave replication only.

Comment: I voted to close because you share absolutely nothing required for anyone to give you an answer. To give you an idea: The answer depends on things such as size of your data set and database traffic.

Comment: well, since for today redis doesn't have cluster feature - question appears irrelevant. And for now my future system is only in my imagine. I guess there can be several sets up to 1000000 items in each. I just hoped that somebody have implemented any system in such way (I mean redis + EC2) and have some life experience about that.

Answer (score 0):

Costing to you will be the cost of bandwidth and instance hours.